# cannot install elementary os on ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, live-installation

I tried to install elementary os from a live USB with unetbootin on Ubuntu, following the instructions on the EOS site. I chose the option to install alongside Ubuntu and created a new 200GB elementary OS partition.

The installer said that everything had worked, and to restart my computer, but now I can only boot into ubuntu, the new partiton appearing as a 200GB external drive.

How can I fix this? I have tried changing the boot order in the startup menu but there is only one UEFI partition to boot from called "ubuntu", and no elementary OS partition, even though it exists on my system.

Comment: I believe OP found their answer below - they just couldn't accept it because it was a disposable account that logged out. An admin could mark this answered to stop Community from bumping it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem from GRUB, the bootloader.

[Would this help?](https://lockone.wordpress.com/2013/12/23/elementary-os-editing-the-grub-bootloader/)

Comment: stupid question, is this a program I should install in ubuntu or in EOS during the live install?

Comment: It is a small software yes, it gives more control over your bootloader. It also means that you can break your computer if you are not careful. I bootload with Win10 and in my case it shows the two OS. You can install in on Ubuntu, you should be about to see them both. If not I would update the grub. At the moment I cannot remember if Ubuntu uses a plain Grub 2.0 as bootlaoader.

Comment: (cannot accept/add another comment as my throwaway account logged out) The answer above worked great - I installed grub-customizer whilst using the live USB I had tried to install eOS with, and then I was able to boot into the correct partition :)

Answer (score 0):

Elementary partitions should be done manually. 
1024 MB mounted as /boot/efi formatted as fat32

Swap 8 GB formatted as swap and mounted as swap

Main partition for system mounted as /

Home partition mounted as /home

Size of main and home depends on you.

You can additionally create var partition but not necessary.

The boot partition do the job.